# Get Posts and Pass them as an additional prop To Another Component With React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, wordpress-rest-api

A react novice here.
I am trying to get custom post type from WordPress rest api and pass the posts object as an additional prop to the built-in Guide component. However, no data is passed. I am able to fetch the posts as array of objects in data.js but not to pass them as props. Please help. I guess I need to use react hooks to change the state, but I do not know how to do it. I do not want to use Classes, Redux or the context api:

`data.js`

```
import useFetch from './helper';
import { Guide} from '@wordpress/components';

const DynamicGuide = (props) => {
    const guides = useFetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/guides');
    console.log(guides); //posts object is printed here
  return (
    <Guide {...props} guides={guides} />
  );
}

export default DynamicGuide;
```

`templates/guide.js`

```
 import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
 import DynamicGuide from './../data'
 
 const WelcomeTourGuide = ( props ) => {
   console.log(props); //posts object is missing here
   return (
     <DynamicGuide { ...props } pages={ [
                {
           image: <img src="https://s.w.org/images/block-editor/welcome-canvas.gif" />,
           content: (
             <div>
               <h2 className="edit-post-welcome-guide__heading">{__('Welcome to the block editor')}</h2>,
               <p className="edit-post-welcome-guide__text">{__('In the WordPress editor, each paragraph, image, or video is presented as a distinct “block” of content.')}</p>
             </div>
           )
                },
            ] }
       >
     </DynamicGuide>
   )
 }
 
 export default WelcomeTourGuide;
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I am not seeing anywhere in the code where you are passing props to the WelcomeTourGuide component

Comment: I want to get all the posts in data.js (managed to do that) and then be able to use them as props in different files (cannot do it). Most notably, i need them in templates/guide.js. However, when i do console.log, it seems that data is missing for some reason.

Comment: guides passed to Guide and not WelcomeTourGuide. console.log in WelcomeTourGuide  print missing guides is all right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, posts is assigned to WelcomeTourGuide nowhere, thats why posts is not in props.
You return it to  which is rendered nowhere, because you don'
t render the children of DynamicGuide.

If you want to use it in the WelcomeTourGuide, which includes the DynamicGuide you could use a hook, for example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useFetch from './helper';

export const getPosts = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState();
 useEffect(() => {
   const getData = async () => {
   const guides = useFetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/guides');
   setData(guides);
  };
  getData();
 }, []);

 return data;
};
```

and then call it in your WelcomeTourGuide

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import DynamicGuide from './../data'
import { getPosts } from './getPosts';

const WelcomeTourGuide = ( props ) => {
  const post = getPosts();
  console.log(post);
  [...]
}

export default WelcomeTourGuide;
```

Since the data is asynchronously fetched, it is possible that posts is still undefined at the beginning.
This can be checked simply with

```
posts.lenght > 0 && console.log(posts)
```

or the hook can be extended by a loading parameter

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epyrx5?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, now i got the posts but they are briefly "undefined" in the guide template and when i try to do something with them i get the error "Error: Minified React error #321".

Comment: You can just use the hook in your guide template or pass it as props

Comment: I tried that but if i do console.log(post[0]) in the template, i am getting an error. For some reason, the post is first undefined and only after some time i am getting the data. By that time, if i try to map the posts, I am getting an error in the component and could not continue. I am sorry, i am very new to react, i probably need some loading check but not sure how to do it..

Comment: Thats correct, the data is fetched asynchronous, so while render it is possible that the data is still undefined. I edited my answer to show you a possible solution

Comment: Awesome, that worked! You made a small typo, it should be "length" instead of "lenght".

Comment: Oh yes. If it works please mark the answer as correct